# How to get link for a preview of firebase storage images

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I want to get a URL like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJswQ.jpg

and this is the firebase link I get:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zendle.appspot.com/o/zeThumbs%2FjgkiXHE.jpeg?alt=media

I want to use the link to check for mature content using this website:
https://moderatecontent.com/

is there any way I can get the preview of the firebase storage images (by getting rid of `?alt=media`)

thanks

Comment: the generated firebase link doesn't have a preview or something and the API can't scan it

Comment: Why do you want to remove that? If you want a URL without the the query params you'll have to use GCS link. Can you share what the actual problem is i.e. what do you mean by "doesn't have a preview"? There might be a solution for that instead of figuring out this.

Comment: I want to use that API to check the images: https://moderatecontent.com/
but it won't work for the firebase storage links.

Comment: The URL must have `&token=` portion as well? You'll have to add that in the URL too

Comment: i tried that, still not working

Comment: i want to get some direct link like this: https://i.imgur.com/jgkiXHE.jpeg

Comment: The API is working for me with Firebase storage URLs. Unsure if URL in your question is valid  but that says 404.

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zendle-aa916.appspot.com/o/zeThumbs%2F-N6mf_eQI9XoGcaC2akh_2?alt=media

Comment: This URL does not have `&token=` part... it returned an error _"Could not retrieve the URL specified, file size too small"_ for me. But I tried downloading your image and uploading to my Firebase project. The API worked fine with the token. Also, your image does not have a PNG extension or similar?

Comment: can you please send me your url?

Comment: Can you try upload the same image with `.png` in your Firebase storage and try along with the "token"?

Comment: Does Dharmaraj's solution in the last comment solve the problem?